# css selector question, how to change font colover of parent li when child ul is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Alright ive been bashing my head against the wall on this one for the last two hours and i have finally given up.

I have a unordered list that has no background at the top level with a text color of `#fff`. and when rolled over the background turns `#fff` and the text color turns `#000`. I also have children ul's that have a background of #fff and text color of `#000`.

Now what i need to know is how do you style that text color change at the top level when the child ul elements are open but the top level links arent moused over. I can't get it to force the top level li's to stay `#000` (i got the background to stick) as soon as i take my mouse off the top level links to move to a child ul the top level text goes back to `#fff`.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li>About
<ul class="children">
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

.menu ul li{
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
}
.menu ul li:hover{
color:#000000
background-color:#ffffff;
}

.children{
background-color:#ffffff;
color:#000000
}
```

This is the markup that i could think of as a best fit scenario. menu ul li has no bg with text color #ffffff. When the user rolls over "About" the background turns to #ffffff, and text turns to #000000. The dropdown falls down and exposes the .children ul/li's. which also have the same bg/text color. as soon as the user moves their mouse off of the parent li link the parent li link goes back to white font on a white background. but the children stays white bg..

I need the font to turn black and white bg for as long as the user is hovered/clicked on a child.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the markup?

Comment: i added markup to original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the Parents function of jquery when you detect child click .

and when you detected the click - you go to its parents  ( where he has some class) - and then

you give the parent the style...

http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/25/edit

Comment: could possibly provide some sort of example ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give each set of grouped elements a shared class, then use jQuery to set the css for all members of the class.  So for menu1, menu2, etc. add the following code:

```
$(".menu_1").hover(
   // on mouseover
  function () {
    $(".menu_1).css("background-color", "red");
  }, 
   // on mouseout
  function () {
    $(".menu_1).css("background-color", "white");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi colon in your css:

```
.menu ul li:hover{
   color:#000000; <!-- insert this semi-colon -->
   background-color:#ff0;
 }
```